# How do I set Angular http calls in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am trying to setup a service to set the http request data. 
I need to set the data in one controller and obtain the data in the another controller when that page is loaded
I have something like

```
angular.module('myApp').service('testService', ['Product','$q',
    function(Product, $q) {
        var products, targetProduct;
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        Product.query({
            Id: 123
            }, function(products) {
                targetProduct = products[0];
                deferred.resolve(products);
        })

        var getTargetProduct = function() {
            var deferredtwo = $q.defer();

            // return deferredtwo.promise;
            deferred.promise.then(function(){
                deferredtwo.resolve(targetProduct);
            })
            return deferredtwo.promise;
        }

        var setTargetProduct = function(targetProduct) {
                targetProduct = targetProduct
        }

        return {
            setTargetProduct: setTargetProduct,
            getTargetProduct: getTargetProduct,
            productPromise : deferred.promise
        };
    }
]);
```

nav controller

```
  testService.productPromise.then(function(products, $rootscope){
      $scope.products= products;
      $scope.targetProduct = products[0];
   })

  //when user click the project  ng-click = setTargetProduct(product);
  $scope.setTargetProduct = function(targetProduct) {
      $rootscope.$broadcast('newProduct' targetProduct);
      testService.setTargetProduct(targetProduct)
   }
```

product detail controller

```
 testService.getTargetProduct().then(function(targetProduct) {
       $scope.$on('newProduct', function(newProduct){
          console.log(newProduct) <---works if both controllers are loaded but undefined if user is not in the product detail page.
       })  
       $scope.targetProduct = targetProduct; 
  })
```

However, if product details controller hasn't been loaded (user is in different page) when user clicks `setTargetProduct`, The newProduct is undefined because the `$scope.$on` is not loaded and can't detect the broadcast. Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your `loadTargetProduct` inside your `$on` callback and if your newProduct is not loaded, use `getTargetProduct` to load it.

```
   $scope.$on('newProduct', function(newProduct){
      if (!(newProduct)){
          //if newProduct is not laoded, load it. 
          testService.getTargetProduct().then(function(targetProduct) {

             $scope.targetProduct = targetProduct; 
          })
       }
   })
```